# Multiple inline elements with overflow:hidden (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I need multiple inline elements that can hide and expand, so I tried putting a bunch of spans inside a wrapper div with `width:0; overflow:hidden`, but now the spans overflow into multiple lines. How do I prevent this? Here is my code (I made width 50px so the problem is easier to see):

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kdw95/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <span>first span</span>
    <span>second span</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width:50px;
    background: lightgrey;
    overflow:hidden;
}
span {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can add

```
white-space:nowrap
```

to the parent element (.wrapper) not the span itself and it would solve the issue.

**EDITED JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/kdw95/2/

Comment: That's it? Oh god...time to rethink my career

Comment: Haha, no! Sometimes you just need another set of eyes or a different look at it. Keep going you'll get to the point where you can spot an issue a mile away!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/kdw95/3/

It looks like a `list` so you SHOULD use a list to do achieve this task :).